# What is the default access modifier for a property in VB6?

Tags: vb6

This sounds like something that should be easy to Google, but it isn't, at least not from a source that *isn't contradicting itself and unreliable*.

What is the default access modifier for a property in VB6?  Is it `Private`, `Friend`, or `Public`?  Does this depend on whether it's in a module, class, form, or user control?  And is it any different for non-properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 Class Properties are Public by default. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266191(v=vs.60).aspx for the Property Get statement explanation.

Answer (score -3):

If not specified, a property is Private.

Comment: Thanks!  If a project is set to use binary compatibility, and if I try to change property to explicitly say `Private`, it'll complain about it.  This is at least able to happen inside a user control.  Do you know why or if it needs some obscure syntax to get it work?

Comment: This is not correct.  Class Properties are public by default. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266191(v=vs.60).aspx for the Property Get statement, the Let and Set statements are similar.

Comment: You refer to a Property Get statement, while the OP request isn't refered to a Get/Set property of a Class but is 'generic' request, therefore my reply can be only 'generic'.